# java-how to check a list of textField with a loop validation function

Tags: java, string, validation, textfield, isnullorempty

i want to check a list of textfield with a validation loop function

if anyone can explain me how to do this thks ;)

i do this :

```
 public void  validation()
    {
       List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
       list.add("LastNameTextField");
       list.add("nameTextField");
       list.add("ageTextField"); 
       list.add("AdressTextField");        
       list.add("PhoneTextField1");        


       for(String check :list )
       {
          if(validator((check.toString()).toString()))
/*here i just want to get the field name and this value */
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, check+ " Empty value");
       }


    }

    public static boolean validator(String TextFieldTextToCheck)
    {
       if ((TextFieldTextToCheck== null) || (TextFieldTextToCheck.length() == 0)) {
            return true ;
        }
       else return false;
    }
```

i dont find the way to get the field value if anyone can help 
thank you for your time

Comment: @RohitJain What is that? :O

Comment: @Eng.Fouad.. Nothing, was just nitpicking. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the record, I don't have allot of Java experience. If I understand correctly, you are trying to validate the contents of several TextFields in a GUI. And the validation only makes certain that the textfield is empty. I would recommend that instead of using a collection of the textField names, you simply use a collection of references to the textfields you wish to validate.

So your ArrayList is populated with textfield references instead:

```
ArrayList<TextField> textFields = new ArrayList<TextField>();
textFields.add(textbox1);
textFields.add(textbox2);
textFields.add(textbox3);
textFields.add(textbox4);
```

You iterate through the ArrayList like before. I used a System.Out call for my own testing.:

```
for(TextField textField : textFields) {
    if(validateTextField(textField)) {
        //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, textField.getText() + " Empty value");
        System.out.println(textField.getName() + " has an Empty value");
    }
}
```

The validate function now looks like this. I added a test for a NULL reference, but you could leave that out.:

```
public static boolean validateTextField(TextField textField) {
    if(textField == null) throw new NullPointerException("The validate function received a null textfield reference. Check your loop.");
    return textField.getText().length() == 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `if` condition is incorrect.

```
    if(validator((check.toString()).toString()))
```

It should be corrected as:

```
   if(YourClass.validator(check))
```

Explanation:

1. `check` is already String. There is not need to call `toString()` on it.
2. `validator` method is a static method so call it in `static` way as `YourClass.validator` where `YourClass` is your class name.
3. `validator` method return `boolean` and `if` expects `boolean` so no need to get a String again.

Comment: but its not a class its my textfield of the gui
and the validator receive the value from textfield.ToString 
and i want to check all my textfield with a loop function

Comment: @Benius What I meant is: you must have defined this method `public static boolean validator(String TextFieldTextToCheck)` in some class, right? Use that class name.

Comment: no im on the ui class
i want to check if the textfield isNoEmpty for example 
and after that i add the information to my user field to add it to the DB

Comment: @Benius :) Use whatsoever class it is. e.g. if you have you code like `public class XYZ { public void  validation(){...} public static boolean validator(String TextFieldTextToCheck){ ......} .....}` then use `XYZ`. Hope this is clear.

Comment: but what they add to me to put it in class 
my problem its to get the fieldName back to check it
i can do if function for each field but i prefer to do the check in loop<br/>
if (validator(textfield.tostring()))
return true;

for example

Comment: @Benius I am missing something from your questions. I am saying it could be simply like : `if(validator(check))`